# Use Validator on another controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

to authenticate me on the login page there is jute need the email and password, like this :

(RegisterController)

```
 protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
           // 'NOM' => ['required', 'string', 'max:50'],
           // 'PRENOM' => ['required', 'string', 'max:50'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:PERSONNELS'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }
```

to avoid overloading the registration page I just asked the user to fill in four fields: First Name, LastName, email and password.

i created UserEdit view to complete and /or update profile : Rue, CP, Ville (street, postcode, city).

on my UserController i worked on `update function`. like this :

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $details = \App\User::find($id);
        if ($request->input('password')==$request->input('password-confirm') && $request->input('password')!='' && $request->input('password-confirm')!='') {
            $details->password = $request->input('password');
            $details->password = Hash::make($details['password']);
        }
        else{
            return redirect()->action('UserController@edit', $id)->withErrors('Mot de passe diférents');
        }

        $membre = auth()->user();

        $details->MATRICULE = $request->input('MATRICULE');
        $details->NOM = $request->input('NOM');
        $details->PRENOM = $request->input('PRENOM');
        $details->RUE = $request->input('RUE');
        $details->CP = $request->input('CP');
        $details->VILLE = $request->input('VILLE');
        $details->email = $request->input('email');

        // $details->id_membre = $membre->id_membre;

        $details->save();
        return redirect()->route('user.edit', $id);
    }
```

i dont understand how to put validator on this function, it's like an inherit class ? and i thought i will have another problem : if the user decides not to change any of his information which is very highly likely, then the unique property will prevent me from updating the data in the table.

and because of my loop if the password must be more than 8 characters but accept 0 is it possible?

Thanks !

Ps I didn't used Matricule because it's depend of admin role.

Comment: OMG sorry i'm Dumb i forgot 'required'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Laravel documentation on how to use validators in your controller methods: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#manually-creating-validators

Ultimately you need to declare your validation within the controller method. If you have created a protected function for validation, then you can call that within methods of the same controller.

The thing is, as it's protected you won't be able to use it in other controllers. This is good though, you do not want to be coupling controllers to one another in ways like this.